# Testing OSX Dotfiles

Tags: macos, dotfiles

I have been pulling all my development environment configs into a dotfiles repository over the past few weeks for my OSX Mojave development environment.  I am able to run my bash script to install everything and it works as you'd expect.  However I want to know if anyone has a way to test this on a fresh install without completely clearing your machine.

I can do something like this on say a ubuntu docker image in any CI service and get a pass fail type test working,  however since it seems like there is no way to get OSX on a docker image, the only way would be to completely wipe your disk and do a fresh install of osx which not only takes a long time and has the potential for data loss, but is not really suitable for anything other than a manual test.  Would really love to get something like this in CI if possible.

Has anyone run into this problem before and found a good way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You could create another user on your device and test the dotfiles with that user. While not as convenient as a virtual machine or docker container, it would isolate the changes from affecting your main user.